# On the conjecture that if $\,\forall\{x, y, z\}\subset \Bbb{Z^+}$ squarefree, and $\ x^3 + y^3 = z^2$, then $\gcd(3, x, y) = 1$.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation, square-numbers, conjectures

I made a conjecture that if $\,\forall\{x, y, z\}\subset\mathbb{Z}^+$ with $x, y, z$ squarefree (not raised to a power greater than $1$; not a *perfect power*), and $$x^3 + y^3 = z^2,$$ then $\gcd(3, x, y) = 1$. I was able to prove my conjecture for all $z$ prime.

---

*Proof*: Let $z$ be a prime number.

Since $(x+y)^3 = x^3 + y^3 + 3xy(x+y),$ then $$\begin{align} x^3 + y^3 &= (x+y)^3 - 3xy(x+y) \\ &= (x+y)\big((x+y)^2-3xy\big) \\ &=(x+y)(x^2 + y^2 - xy).\tag1\end{align}$$ Therefore, we need integer solutions such that $(*)\,\, x + y = x^2 + y^2 - xy$ because $(1) = z^2$, follows that $$\begin{align} 0 &= x^2 + y^2 - xy - x - y \\ &= x(x - 1) + y(y - 1) - xy \\ \Leftrightarrow 3xy &= x(x-1) + y(y-1) + 2xy.\end{align}$$ Since $3xy$ is not a square number, this means that $x \neq 3y$, $y\neq 3x$ and $3\neq xy$.

Therefore $\gcd(3, x, y) = 1$ for this case, but there is also another case where $(**)\,\, x + y = z$ and $x^2 + y^2 - xy = 1$. Of course $x + y\neq 1$ because $x, y\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, thus we need to consider statement $(**)$. $$\begin{align} x^3 + y^3 &= (x+y)^2 \\ \Leftrightarrow (x+y)(x^2 + y^2 - xy) &= (x+y)^2 \\ \Leftrightarrow x^2 + y^2 - xy &= x + y\tag*{$\unicode{x21af}$ (Contradiction)}\end{align}$$ Therefore, statement $(*)$ must always be true, i.e. $\gcd(3, x, y) = 1$.$\quad\quad\quad\quad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\Box$

---

Of course if $z$ is not prime, then $x+y$ does not necessarily have to equal $x^2 + y^2 - xy$. Take $z = 6$ for example, then $z^2 = 6^2 =6\times 6$ but it also equals $9\times 4$, etc.

Could somebody prove/disprove my conjecture *for all* $z\in\mathbb{Z^+}$? Along with that, is my proof valid?

Thank you in advance.

---

**Edit:**

The symbol $\unicode{x21af}$ (Harry Potter's Scar) is used to symbolise a contradiction in this case. Most people prefer $\Rightarrow\Leftarrow$, so if you prefer that instead, treat the Scar as if it were the arrows.

Comment: $x=9,y=18,z=81$.

Comment: @lulu nice counter-example. But is there a way to demonstrate that my conjecture is false based on a written proof? Also, we have $x = 3^2$ and $z = 9^2$ Which now makes the equation $x^4 + y^2 = z^4$. I will extend my conjecture...

Comment: Why isn't a counterexample a written proof?  Also: as a general point, it's dangerous to rush to modify conjectures as counterexamples appear.  Questions like these...first thing to do is to check a lot of examples.  I found this example in less than a minute...do a deeper search for more examples.

Comment: @lulu is a counter-example a written proof? I mean a proof without the use of counter-examples..... Oh, and ok. I will do some deeper searches.

Comment: what do you mean :with x,y,z not raised to a power greater than 1. x,y,z squarefree, or they are not perfect powers?

Comment: Since there is only *one* prime $z$ such that $x^3+y^3 = z^2$ for positive integers $x,y$, this proof contributes no insight regarding your conjecture.  Some might say that this is symptomatic of what happens when one has neglected to consider examples and only engaged in symbolic manipulation :).

Comment: @ErickWong I never knew there was only one prime $z$, namely $3$ of course, that satisfies the equation. I just assumed there was more than one.

Comment: @user477343 Well, you saw in your proof that because $x^3+y^3$ is a reducible polynomial, the conditions under which it is the square of a prime are very restricted.  It isn’t hard to see from there that the restrictions are so tight that they only admit one value.  Regardless of the precise number of examples, it is clear that this specific case does not represent the general case at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated your conjecture is false. 
I supposed that $x,y$ are squarefree integers.
The following paramertization holds,
$$ x = s^{4} + 6 \, s^{2} t^{2} - 3 \, t^{4}, \ 
y = -s^{4} + 6 \, s^{2} t^{2} + 3 \, t^{4},\  
z =  6 \, {\left(s^{4} + 3 \, t^{4}\right)} s t$$
(See for instance lemma 3.2.6 of Zagier http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/~nbruin/thesis.pdf).
Then we get many solutions with $\gcd(x,y,3)>1$ and $x,y,z>0.$
For instance $s=-3,t=2$ provides $(x,y,z)=(249, 183, 4644)$
or $s=-3,t=4$ gives $(x,y,z)=(177, 1551, 61128).$

In your proof, there are more conditions except $x+y=x^2+y^2-xy$ that implies $(1)=z^2$, e.g. $x+y = ab, x^2+y^2-xy=abc^2.$

Comment: Nice answer! I have never heard of that Lemma before, so thank you for letting me know, and congratulations! $$(+1) \ \ \color{green}{\checkmark}$$